# Multiple domains map/redirect with CNAME to one domain with different path

Tags: dns, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cname

we are building online shops for deliveries, we are using Kubernetes cluster with nginx ingress to host the online shops

Our online shops are accessible via URL shop.mycompany.com/{customer_number}.

assuming we have two customers who want to use our online shops but with customer's own domain name.
example customer1 -> [www.customer1.com](http://www.customer1.com)
and customer2 -> [www.customer2.com](http://www.customer2.com).

that means [www.customer1.com](http://www.customer1.com) should point to shop.mycompany.com/customer1 and #
[www.customer2.com](http://www.customer2.com) should point to shop.mycompany.com/customer2

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Thx. a lot.

Comment: That is achievable via NGINX, you can use proxy_pass and map your requests based on different domains to same project

Comment: if I will have 1k domains, which should be maped to 1k different customer_numbers. is it still right way?

Comment: For that you can use Caddy Server, which is an alternative to Nginx. They have APIs to add and remove domains. Also, a popular feature implements SSL automatically to every domain added via API.